# Find repeating values of a certain value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, gaps-and-islands

I have a table similar to:

| Date | Person | Distance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022/01/01 | John | 15 |
| 2022/01/02 | John | 0 |
| 2022/01/03 | John | 0 |
| 2022/01/04 | John | 0 |
| 2022/01/05 | John | 19 |
| 2022/01/01 | Pete | 25 |
| 2022/01/02 | Pete | 12 |
| 2022/01/03 | Pete | 0 |
| 2022/01/04 | Pete | 0 |
| 2022/01/05 | Pete | 1 |

I want to find all persons who have a distance of 0 for 3 or more consecutive days.
So in the above, it must return John and the count of the days with a zero distance.
I.e.

| Person | Consecutive Days with Zero |
| --- | --- |
| John | 3 |

I'm looking at something like this, but I think this might be way off:

```
Select Person, count(*), 
       (row_number() over (partition by Person, Date order by Person, Date))
from mytable
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided I understand your requirement you could, for your sample data, just calculate the difference in days of a windowed min/max date:

```
select distinct Person, Consecutive from (
  select *, DateDiff(day,
    Min(date) over(partition by person), 
    Max(date) over(partition by person)
  ) + 1 Consecutive
  from t
  where distance = 0
)t
where Consecutive >= 3;
```

Example [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5437fdb80c7b0bc3d336ff7f50a82560)

If you can have gaps in the dates you could try the following that only considers rows with 1 day between each date (and could probably be simplified):

```
with c as (
  select *, Row_Number() over (partition by person order by date) rn, 
    DateDiff(day, Lag(date) over(partition by person order by date), date) c
  from t
  where distance = 0
), g as (
  select Person, rn - Row_Number() over(partition by person, c order by date) grp
  from c
)
select person, Count(*) + 1 consecutive
from g
group by person, grp
having Count(*) >= 2;
```

Comment: The 2nd query worked well and is exactly what I require.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to:

- transform your "*Distance*" values into a boolean, where distance of 0 becomes 1 and any other value becomes zero
- compute a running sum over your transformed "*Distance*" values in a window of three rows, using a frame specification clause
- filter out any "*Person*" value which has at least one sum of 3.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, SUM(CASE WHEN Distance = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER(
                  PARTITION BY Person 
                  ORDER     BY Date_ 
                  ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
              ) AS window_of_3
    FROM tab
)
SELECT DISTINCT Person 
FROM cte
WHERE window_of_3 = 3
```

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1c6175a5319ed025c3b60843f8488667).

**Note**: This solution requires your table to have no missing dates. In case missing dates is a possible scenario, then it's necessary to add missing rows corresponding to the dates not found for each "*Person*" value, for this solution to work.

Comment: Wow, thanks a mil. The answer is correct and works well. The solution in the other answer is serving my purposes slightly better. I wish I could accept both.